# Why is my firewall question off-topic?

Tags: support, closed-questions, off-topic

Question is [Block TCP/UDP high-latency connections](https://superuser.com/questions/1527129/ban-high-ping-co-op-players-detect-and-block-high-latency-tcp-udp-connections)

- I thought it clearly fits "personal and home computer networking" category, as listed in Help Center.
- Other questions on intersection of [gaming](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/gaming) and [networking](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/networking) do exist, thus mine does not seems an anomaly. (Should I add these tags? If yes, which tags to replace?)
- Finally, it's not or not exactly software recommendation question. I suppose my problem may be solved through firewall/router configuration, perhaps with some scripting, but that's just my guess.

Can I improve the question or where should I migrate it? Though I don't see other places that fit.

Comment: You are asking for software and/or hardware recommendations, which are explicitly off topic on [su]

Comment: @DavidPostill you are implying that my problem can't be solved with built-in firewall. This is not obvious at all.

Comment: voted to re-open